# how to add a line by data received in real time in d3.js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Before reading this question, you should know that I had asked a similar question, but by the advice of this community I was asked to do it again being a little more specific.

I have 7 sensors represented by a radio button each. in my real project I'm constantly receiving a web service, and I make filters for each sensor. the user is only interested in seeing the information by sensor. I am simulating the web service with a setinterval This is an example of the structure of the web service that I can receive. Do not worry about scale or values. the value 400 in the third data(data[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nnokx.gif)) becomes a peak, is a dummy value for this test.

```
[{"id":"sensor1_ciclo1","sensor":1,"ciclo":"ciclo1","values":
 [
  {"voltaje":0,"corriente":11.175}
 ]
```

oData is the simulation of my webservice.. oData[0],oData[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mtaMv.jpg) and oData[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nnokx.gif)

```
cont=0;
intervalo=setInterval(function(){
 if(cont<=2){
  reloadPoints(oData[cont]);
  cont++;
 }
},3000)
```

the `"sensor"` key represents the sensor number. I have 7 input radios to represent each sensor.the key "ciclo", is a property of the sensor. I can filter for this property. Although, in this case, all my data are using `"ciclo": "ciclo1"`. In the line chart I draw the points using the keys `"corriente"` and `"voltaje"`.

In my real project, I get the data according to a n amount of time, for this case I am simulating them with a `setInterval` of 3 seconds. I want to paint the data that corresponds to the selected sensor with an animation. if the sensor1 is selected, I only want to put the sensor1 data.

If I change sensor, I would like to see the data that has been accumulated, and this is the main function of my function `reloadPoints` the accumulated values are in `oDataSensores`. The `display` function is responsible for drawing the data, and if the limit is greater than 250 or -250 on the y-axis, the chart is rescaled.

[image]

I do not know how to fix it. The really strangest thing is that if I comment this line,

```
 Array.prototype.push.apply(oDataSensores[data[i].id].content.values, data[i].values);
```

it apparently works. But I need to accumulate the values by sensor so I can not delete this line. How can I solve that?

To reproduce the error, wait 9 seconds, and when the third line in sensor1 is added and the chart is rescaled (>250), this problem occurs.

look the gif please.

[image]

I do not know how to fix it. The really strangest thing is that if I comment this line,

```
 Array.prototype.push.apply(oDataSensores[data[i].id].content.values, data[i].values);
```

it apparently works. But I need to accumulate the values by sensor so I can not delete this line. How can I solve that?

that second time that I click on sensor 1, is not correct..

To reproduce the error, wait 9 seconds, and when the third line in sensor1 is added and the chart is rescaled (>250), this problem occurs.

so is the process that I want to achieve when a new point is added

[image]

This is my code:

http://plnkr.co/edit/z5It4hiOy3i7YOE5phnd?p=preview

so that you understand a little my project. I have 7 sensors. I will constantly be consuming a web service with the structure of my data. each time they are going to paint the lines for each sensor, according to the attribute "ciclo" (in this case all are "ciclo1"). while I am getting data and showing it in real time, I can change the sensor to display the data accumulated up to that point.

Comment: "*created with gifrecorder.com*" For future reference, [LICEcap](https://www.cockos.com/licecap/) might be a better alternative without any watermarks.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 okay. What do you think? is my problem understood?

Comment: I've been poking around your plunkr. I think the issue might be with your dummy data, as if you look at how the line segments form, the weird stuff seems to be part of the first segment. Going to continue to continue to try some stuff out.

Comment: @PAckerman thank you very much. but the only dummy is the one that is 400 and becomes a peak. I thank you for helping me, do not give up please. Thank you.

Comment: Here's the version that I made for him: http://plnkr.co/edit/yfPqBwH4JyD1pi6JAbJ8?p=preview

As far as I can tell what he doesn't like about it is that it re-draws the line every time there's new data instead of continuing to draw the old line.  I don't know of a way to get the animation to happen AND the y-scale redraw of the first line to happen when the value goes above 250.